# Density of gradients in $L^\infty$ w.r.t $L^2$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, approximation-theory, dense-subspaces

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be smooth bounded domain. Let
$$G=\{\nabla f : f\in C^2(\overline{D})\}.$$
Is this space dense in $L^\infty(D)^2$ w.r.t the topology of $L^2$? I have the intuition that this is not true. Maybe, it could be true if we add some condition, but I'm looking for a large class so that the result holds.

Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Not really what you are asking for, but if you use $$C(\overline{D}, \mathbb{C}^2)\cong C(\overline{D}\times \{1,2\}, \mathbb{C}), \left((x,y) \mapsto (f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)) \right) \mapsto \left( (x,y,i) \mapsto f_i(x,y) \right)$$ then you can use Stone-Weierstrass to conclude that the algebra generated by $G$ is dense in $C(\overline{D}, \mathbb{C}^2)$, which is dense in $L^2(\overline{D})^2$ in the $L^2$-topology. The problem with this argument is of course, that $G$ is not closed under the multiplication $(f_1, f_2) \cdot (g_1, g_2) = (f_1 \cdot g_1, f_2\cdot g_2)$.

Comment: Another unrelated remark. It is not true if you put $H^1$ instead of $L^2$. As the limit would always have curl zero (gradients have curl zero and because our space has finite measure, $L^2$ convergence of the gradients implies $L^1$ convergence of the gradients and hence the limiting function has still curl zero), which is not true for a general $L^\infty(D)^2$ function.

Comment: What I meant was that it would not even be dense in $C^1(D)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. Gradient fields have zero curl, but general vector fields do not have this property. You cannot even approximate all $C^1$-vector fields.

Take $g\in C^1(\bar D)^2$. Take $f_n \in C^2(\bar D)$ such that $\nabla f_n \to g$ in $L^2(D)$. Let $v\in C_c^\infty(D)$. Then
$$
0=\int_D \nabla \times \nabla f_n(x) \cdot v(x)dx 
= -\int_D \nabla f_n(x) \cdot (\nabla \times v(x)) dx \\
\to 
 -\int_D  \int_D g(x) \cdot (\nabla \times v(x)) dx = \int_D \nabla \times g \cdot v(x) dx.
$$
Hence $\nabla \times g=0$ necessarily. If $g$ would be just in $L^2(D)^2$, the same reasoning shows that the curl of $g$ (in the weak sense) is zero.

In general, one has the following result for Lipschitz domain $D$:
$$
L^2(D)^n = \{ \nabla p: \ p\in H^1_0(D)\} \otimes^\perp
\{u\in L^2(D)^n : \ div(u)=0, \ u\cdot n=0 \text{ on } \partial D\}.
$$
The conditions on $u$ in the second set have to be formulated in a weak sense.
For a reference, see Temam: Navier Stokes equations, or any other book on Navier Stokes equations. The first set can be further decomposed.
Iirc, elements in these subspaces can be approximated by smooth functions from these spaces.

Hence, gradients of smooth vector fields are always orthogonal to divergence-free vector fields.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). But I guess you mean $g$ in $H^1(D)^2$.

Comment: No: If $g\in L^2(D)^2$ then the last integration by parts is not valid. However the argument shows that $g$ has to be orthogonal to curls of vector fields, which is still a restriction.

Comment: Sure, this yields a suitable restriction that does not hold true in general. I just find it easier to think about this if $g$ really admits a weak derivative that is a function.

Comment: @daw what if we add that condition on curl, do we have density in this case? Maybe, we have general decomposition as sum of gradient and an orthogonal explicit vector?

Comment: see edit, there is a decomposition theorem for vector fields into gradients and divergence-free fields.